# Could not find a part of the path 'D:\OLMS\'

Tags: asp.net

```
Protected Sub btnadd_sylbus_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadd_sylbus.Click
    Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower()
    Dim Type As String = Nothing
    If (extension = ".pdf") Then
        Dim intFileNameLength As Integer
        Dim strFileNamePath As String
        Dim strFileNameOnly As String
        strFileNamePath = FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.FileName
        intFileNameLength = InStr(1, StrReverse(strFileNamePath), "\")
        strFileNameOnly = Mid(strFileNamePath, (Len(strFileNamePath) - intFileNameLength) + 2)
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.InputStream)
        FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.SaveAs("D:\OLMS\" & strFileNameOnly)
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Syllabus(sylbus_id, sylbus_name, file_name, content) values(@id,@name,@file,@cont)"
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", txtsylbus_id.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", txtsylbus_name.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@file", FileUpload_sylbus.FileName)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cont", br.ReadBytes(FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.ContentLength))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        lbladd_sylbus.Visible = True
        lbladd_sylbus.Text = "File Upload Success."
        txtsylbus_id.Text = Nothing
        txtsylbus_name.Text = Nothing
    Else
        lbladd_sylbus.Visible = True
        lbladd_sylbus.Text = "Not a Valid file format"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain why you correctly started to use the methods on the Path class to work with filename parts and then suddenly revert to a convoluted and error prone way to extract the filename? Path.GetFileName doesn't work?

Comment: sorry but i got this source code from internet i have my project path to D:\OLMS when i try to debug and upload the file it says could not find a part of the path D:\OLMS

Comment: Usually you cannot access paths that lie outside the root folder of your site. This could be bypassed but it is not clear in which context this code runs. Is it on your external site (on you hosting company pcs?) or did you run it in your internal network where you could easily change the permissions for your site? In any case the best practice is to store files inside the root folder of your site and using Server.MapPath to reach these relative paths

Comment: its on my internal network i have stored my files which are to be uploaded in root folder D:\OLMS\  now i did it with Server.MapPath
FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\OLMS\" & strFileNameOnly))  this occured "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." am i doing it wrong ? help

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code

```
strFileNamePath = FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.FileName
strFileNameOnly = Path.GetFilename(strFileNamePath)
Dim newFileNamePath as String = Path.Combine("D:\OLMS", strFileNameOnly)
Dim br As New BinaryReader(FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.InputStream)
FileUpload_sylbus.PostedFile.SaveAs(newFileNamePath)
```

Now, if you still get errors in accessing the folder `D:\OLMS` then you have this path outside the root folder of your site and your machine configuration (search about MEDIUM TRUST) disallows writing outside the root folder. (Of course I am assuming that the folder `D:\OLMS` exists and the user under which the IIS ASP.NET service is running has all the permissions to write in that folder)